# Normal ordering of momentum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I've found that the momentum operator of a real free scalar field is
$$P^i=\int d^3 {p}\frac{p^i}{2}(a(p)a^\dagger(p)+a^\dagger(p)a(p)).$$
However, problem 3.5 in A First Book on Quantum Field Theory states that there is no need of normal ordering the momentum operator for the real free scalar theory. Not only do I not see this reflected in my result but I also don't think this should be physically true. The field can be thought as an infinite array of quantum oscillators each with finite momentum. Therefore, momenta should diverge. Any help is much appreciated!

(BTW: I wanted to upload a latex version of my proof. Is there any way to upload code from latex on stackexchange?)

Comment: Did you do the right calculations? I think there is only the term $a^\dagger a$ in the expression of momentum, so the normal ordering is no longer needed (since it is already there).
Btw, i think stackexchange posts are of the TeX format, so you just need to copy and paste your latex code (the body)

Comment: I've checked my calculation and can't find any errors. The problem is that I cannot import the physics package to show you. Is there however any reference you know of that shows this?

Comment: Or to arrive at that you must use the argument in the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The momentum operator $$\underline P = -\int \text{d}^3 x \, \pi(x) \cdot \nabla \phi(x)$$ with the relevant field mode decompositions inserted gives $$P^i \sim \int \text{d}^3 p  \frac{p^i}{\omega(p)} \left(a(p) a(p)^{\dagger} + a(p)^{\dagger} a(p) \right) $$ as you write.

One can write this in terms of the number operator $N(p) \equiv a(p)^{\dagger} a(p)$ via $$P^i \sim \int \text{d}^3 p \frac{p^i}{\omega(p)} \left(N(p) + \frac{1}{2} [a(p), a(p)^{\dagger}]\right).$$

This is analogous to the expression for the Hamiltonian $H$ and the normal ordering argument was used as a means of justifying the irrelevance of the infinity arising from $[a(p),a(p)^{\dagger}] \sim \delta^3(0)$. Here no such normal ordering prescription need be invoked because the integration of the commutator term over the sphere in momentum space gives contributions from fourier modes with momentum $-p$ and $p$ such that they all cancel $^\dagger$.

So the latter term in the last display vanishes and, as expected, we find the vacuum exhibiting zero total momentum, $\langle 0 | \underline P | 0 \rangle = 0$.

$^\dagger$ Such a manipulation is common in these types of calculations, but one can proceed more carefully by first regulating the integral by considering a finite (symmetric) volume and then finish by taking the appropriate limit.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to make sure I understand, we can conclude that $P^i=\int d^3p p^i N(p)$?

Comment: @IvánMauricioBurbano Yes indeed, up to some factors.